# How to keep main thread in waiting state after spawn multiple async jobs in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have configured async job launcher using TaskExecutor in spring batch.

I have launched n async jobs from main thread.

Now I want to keep main method wait till all n jobs get complete. I have tried to use CountDownLatch and Phaser but could not achieve.

Please suggest how to achieve it?

Here are some similar dummy code fragments.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBatchConfiguration { 
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxThreadCount);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepo, SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecuter) {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobL = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobL.setJobRepository(jobRepo);
        jobL.setTaskExecutor(taskExecuter);
        return jobL;
    }
}
```

Main thread executing below code.

```
 Class JobHandler {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    // Main thread executing demo method

    public void demo () {
        launchJob(job1, builder1);
        launchJob(job2, builder2);
        launchJob(job3, builder3);
        launchJob(job4, builder4);
        launchJob(job5, builder5);
        launchJob(job6, builder6);

        // Here I want to do operation when all six jobs complete successfully
        // Please suggest how to do.
    }

    public void launchJob(Job job, JobParametersBuilder builder ) { 
        try {

            // Asynchronous job submission  
            final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());     
        }
        catch(Throwable th) {
            log.error("Job execution failed");
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is the way to go. This task executor implementation provides a boolean parameter called `WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` which you need to set in order to wait for jobs to finish. So what you can do is the following:

Set the `WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` on the task executor:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(maxThreadCount);
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Call `shutdown` on the task executor to wait for jobs to finish:

```
Class JobHandler {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    // Main thread executing demo method

    public void demo () {
       launchJob(job1, builder1);
       launchJob(job2, builder2);
       launchJob(job3, builder3);
       launchJob(job4, builder4);
       launchJob(job5, builder5);
       launchJob(job6, builder6);

       // Here I want to do operation when all six jobs complete successfully
       // Please suggest how to do.
       taskExecutor.shutdown();
    } 

}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobsConfig {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    private final StepBuilderFactory steps;

    public JobsConfig(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job1() {
        return jobs.get("job1")
                .start(steps.get("step11")
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("job1");
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        })
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job2() {
        return jobs.get("job2")
                .start(steps.get("step21")
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("job2");
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        })
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository, ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JobsConfig.class);
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = context.getBean(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job1 = (Job) context.getBean("job1");
        Job job2 = (Job) context.getBean("job2");
        jobLauncher.run(job1, new JobParameters());
        jobLauncher.run(job2, new JobParameters());
        System.out.println("submitted 2 jobs, waiting for completion..");
        taskExecutor.shutdown();
    }

}
```

It prints:

```
submitted 2 jobs, waiting for completion..
job1
job2
```

Comment: Along with setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown, I had to add setAwaitTerminationSeconds. Otherwise, the application is killed instantly.

Comment: I don't know which JVM you use, but the sample above works with OpenJDK and waits for both jobs to finish without `setAwaitTerminationSeconds`. As a user, I should not be concerned with the duration of tasks or guess how long they will take to finish and `setAwaitTerminationSeconds`. The task executor should wait for tasks to finish, no matter how long they take. I can of course set a threshold, but it should not be mandatory (or else the application is killed instantly as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

When using an Executor, we can shut it down by calling the shutdown() or shutdownNow() methods. Although, it won’t wait until all threads stop executing.

Waiting for existing threads to complete their execution can be achieved by using the `awaitTermination(TIME_IN_SECONDS)`  & `setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true)` method which blocks the thread until all tasks complete their execution or the specified timeout is reached

```
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskExecutor.awaitTermination(10000)
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    Class JobHandler {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    // Main thread executing demo method

    public void demo () {
       launchJob(job1, builder1);
       launchJob(job2, builder2);
       launchJob(job3, builder3);
       launchJob(job4, builder4);
       launchJob(job5, builder5);
       launchJob(job6, builder6);

       // Here I want to do operation when all six jobs complete successfully
       // Please suggest how to do.
       taskExecutor.shutdown();
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to explore ExecutorService invokeAll() method which will execute all callable task defined and return Future object

try this reference code :

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();

callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Job1";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Job 2";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "job 3";
    }
});

List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);

for(Future<String> future : futures){
    System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
}

executorService.shutdown();
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I need to launch job using jobLauncher of spring batch. In spring batch there is already interface JabLauncher.

Comment: same you can try with executorservice, it will work